# How to get the mac terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding on the new macs?

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, apple-m1, capacitor

i have searched other answers to this question and they all say to edit the .zshrc or .profile files however these do not exist on my system even with hidden files shown.

I have a feeling there is a different solution for the new M1 macs, maybe these files have a new location

trying to run a pod install on an ionic capacitor project and receiving this error:

```
 WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

does anyone have an idea?

thank you in advance!

nb ive been on this problem for two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.zshrc and .profile only exist if someone creates them. You do that in Terminal with

```
touch ~/.zshrc
touch ~/.profile
```

Check what shell you are using. In Terminal

```
echo $SHELL
```

It is recommended to use the Z shell, you change this with

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

and then you need to restart Terminal for it to take effect. I think with the Z shell .profile may be ignored, and only .zshrc may be used.

Quite likely there is no real change how the M1 Macs work compared to Intel Macs; you just created these files on your old Mac many years ago and have all forgotten about it.

Comment: thank you, it turns out i did have to create the files like you said,  with this and the commands from this https://errorsfixing.com/flutter-simulator-doesnt-work-on-android-studio-but-works-through-xcode/ the error managed to sort itself out and build correctly. Thank you again for the quick response!

Comment: It is recommended BY APPLE to use zsh, because bash is no longer updated. OP can still use bash if he updates it (homebrew, macports, etc). I think it's better clarified because abandoning bash was Apple's decision (because of a dumb license). How they sold zsh as a replacement is not much different from the Airpods/headphone jack situation.